# How can I make sikulix type the text I've extracted from an image?

Tags: python, automation, sikuli-x

I want to make my program take a screenshot of a region, read the text on the image (I've completed this part) and type it out with keypresses (This is the part I need help with)

So far I have this:

```
a=find(This is where I put my screenshot).text()
print a
```

This takes a screenshot, reads it for text and prints the text in the message box.
How do I turn that output into keypresses?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
switchApp("textedit") # put the target window to foreground
for x in a: 
    type(x)
```

RaiMan from SikuliX (you might have to learn some Python basics and look into the SikuliX docs)